# Not able lock key using node-redlock it gives error

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I want lock the key ("ProjectData:GSTest") which is present in redis database. I am using below code to achive this goal but it gives error please let me know what is going wrog here.

```
const redlock = new Redlock(
  // You should have one client for each independent redis node
  // or cluster.
  [client],
  {
    // The expected clock drift; for more details see:
    // http://redis.io/topics/distlock
    driftFactor: 0.01, // multiplied by lock ttl to determine drift time

    // The max number of times Redlock will attempt to lock a resource
    // before erroring.
    retryCount: 20,

    // the time in ms between attempts
    retryDelay: 200, // time in ms

    // the max time in ms randomly added to retries
    // to improve performance under high contention
    // see https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html
    retryJitter: 200, // time in ms

    // The minimum remaining time on a lock before an extension is automatically
    // attempted with the `using` API.
    automaticExtensionThreshold: 500, // time in ms
  }
);
console.log('Before acquire lock');
let lock = await redlock.acquire(["ProjectData:GSTest"], 120000);
console.log('Afetr  acquire lock');
try {
  // Do something...
  //await something();

  // Extend the lock. Note that this returns a new `Lock` instance.
  lock = await lock.extend(5000);

  // Do something else...
  //await somethingElse();
} finally {
  // Release the lock.
  await lock.release();
}
}
```

Error

Before acquire lock
(node:20868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ExecutionError: The operation was unable to achieve a quorum during its retry
window.
at Redlock._execute (Test\node_modules\redlock\dist\cjs\index.js:296:23)
at async Redlock.acquire (Test\node_modules\redlock\dist\cjs\index.js:213:34)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: can any one help here..

Comment: I have one observation on it. It fails when i am trying to lock on key which is present in redis db. same code works fine if i will give key string which is not present in redis db.

Comment: I am also new to this but I guess what happens is, it retries 20 times after which it will throw error. Since you dont have a catch block the execution fails altogether. Add a catch block for cases when acquiring throws error. Also, if you go through algo, acquiring lock basically stores a set in redis with key as resource name and some random value (which expires after given time). so if you attempt to set the key again with new random value before the previous one expires, it keeps on retrying and at last throws error. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a Redis in cluster mode? This error indicates that `redlock` tries to reach multiple nodes / cluster in order to lock a variable through all connected nodes.
The Redlock algorithm, which is a distributed lock implementation, is designed to run on multiple Redis instances. The algorithm uses a quorum of Redis instances to achieve consensus on lock ownership and to ensure that the lock is only held by a single client at a time. Because it requires multiple instances to work, it would not be able to function properly on a single Redis instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error might also happen when you choose a very short ttl when calling acquire().